# Can you put a list item numeral on its own line?

Tags: html, css, list

I have an `<ol>` set to `list-style-position: inside` but I can't seem to control where the numerals appear. I want them to appear on a line above the content it presents, but I can't seem to control the behavior.

It is showing like this:

> I Item 1
>  II Item 2

When I want it to show like this:

> I
>  Item 1
>  II
>  Item II

It seems easy but I haven't found anything on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**-- EDIT : CSS solution --**

You can use the `:before` pseudo element to create a line before your content like this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/PSbuM/2/)**

```
li:before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
}
```

---

**HTML solution:**

The simplest I can think of is to use `<br/>` tags at the bigining of the `<li>`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/PSbuM/)**

```
<ol>
    <li><br/>item 1</li>
    <li><br/>item 2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Nice, i tried to exploit `:before` as well but didn't think of `list-style-position: inside;`

Comment: I can't do the line break trick because it's for a responsive project that needs inline-outside numerals on larger breakpoints, but the pseudo class worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @BenTinsley Yes, I think it is the neetest solution too even for non-responsive projects. Glad I could help :)